# Sequelize findAll() with where-parameter returns null while findByPk() returns correct data

Tags: node.js, graphql, sequelize.js

I'm setting up resolvers for a GraphQL API right now and running into some problems/questions regarding the findAll() function from sequelize.

I have these 2 resolvers:

```
User: async (parent, { id }, { models }) => {
  return await models.User.findAll({
    where: {
      ID_User: id
    }
  });
}

UserPK: async (parent, { id }, { models }) => {
  return await models.User.findByPk(id);
}
```

Models:

```
type Query {
  UserPK(id: ID): User
  User(id: ID): User
}
type User {
  ID_User: ID,
  Username: String,
}
```

If I now run these queries

```
{
 UserPK(id: 1) {
    ID_User
    Username
  }
 User(id: 1) {
    ID_User
    Username
  }
}
```

Only the UserPK returns (correct) data, the User query returns null for every field which confuses me because the queries sequelize executes are exactly the same.

```
Executing (default): SELECT `ID_User`, `Username` FROM `User` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`ID_User` = '1';
Executing (default): SELECT `ID_User`, `Username` FROM `User` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`ID_User` = '1';
```

I'm using apollo server btw if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between `findByPk` and `findAll` is that `findByPk` returns already a single element whereas `findAll` returns and array. You don't seem to take that into account. After that the resolvers for `User` receive an array where they cannot read properties from.

```js
return (await models.User.findAll({
  where: {
    ID_User: id
  }
}))[0];
```

Comment: Ah that makes so much sense now. Thanks for the quick answer, both return the same now!

Comment: Sometimes all the _implicit_ resolvers are not helpful when it comes to errors :( Glad it works now!